# Backticks vs. four leading spaces: Code font changes

Tags: bug, code-formatting

In the new flat theme, the font used for code formatting is different depending on what code marker is used (backticks vs. four leading spaces).

Backticks yield the font from the old theme, while four leading spaces yield a smaller font size.

``` code formatted using the `` bacticks ```

`12345678901234567890`

```
code formatted using the four leading spaces
12345678901234567890
```

Looks like a bug to me. Is it?

Or is this intentional — to allow posters to fit even greater walls of code on our screens?

Either way, it still makes ["certain answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28004325/119775) looks a bit silly.

---

---

Preserved as screenshot for future generations:

[image]

Comment: ... obviously the "already has an answer" part is **not true** but let's keep the discussion/request in a single thread for convenience.